# How to use github project as library in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, github, library-project

Hi I have been trying to add [this](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui) library project to my existing project in Eclipse. Its the first time I am going to use a library project and I am having tough time. looked around for may ways from tutorials and posts around but couldn't get it done.

I hope I can get help from this wonderful community I am a part of.

This is my xml..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"

   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <at.markushi.ui.ActionView

   android:id="@+id/action"

   android:layout_width="56dip"

   android:layout_height="56dip"

   android:padding="16dip"

   app:av_color="@android:color/white"

   app:av_action="drawer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The tag `<at.markushi.ui.ActionView/>` is giving error and i am unable to import `at.markushi.ui.ActionView` in my main activity.

Comment: tell the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: when i try to add <at.markushi.ui.ActionView /> xml tag from [this](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui) in my project xml file it gives error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the project in your workspace
2. Check isLibrary
3. Use it on your project
   [image]

   For more details please refer to the developer documentation page, [setting up a library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Comment: i have added lib like this. but when i try to add <at.markushi.ui.ActionView /> xml tag from [this](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui) in my project xml file it gives error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix.

Comment: Could you post your xml? @Utkarsh

Comment: @Utkarsh you have made it private, so could not see it. Try to add it your question by editing.